# Rename a file before attaching it to Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can I edit the name of a .pdf file before attaching it to an Outlook email?

I have a 10 digit value in R.Offset(0, 3) cell with format: 0000000000
I want to find the file in a folder with format: 0000000000_FIRST_MIDDLE_LAST_STATEMENT

Those 10 digits are GDPR sensitive so I have to remove them from the name of the file.
Sometimes those numbers are like this 0000000000-1 and sometimes are 8 digits: 00000000

Credits for the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8yE3Bh_5_s

```vb
Sub SendEmailFromExcel()

Dim EApp As Outlook.Application
Set EApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim EItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim path As String
Dim strbody
path = "\" 'put your path here
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))
Dim R As Range

strbody = "<p >template</p>" 

For Each R In RList
    Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
    With EItem
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = ("team_email")
        .To = R.Offset(0, 1)
        .Subject = R.Offset(0, 0)
        .Attachments.Add (path & R.Offset(0, 3) + ".pdf")
        .Display
        .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
    End With
Next R
Set EApp = Nothing
Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: So you want to strip away all characters from the filename up to and including the first underscore?

Comment: @CLR Yes, the first underscore would be great, there are no requiremets how the actual name of the file needs to be.

Comment: @braX saw another thread with the same reference to Name statement but I don't really know how to implement that into my code.

Comment: Can you copy the file to a temp directory with the same name eg attachment.pdf, attach and send email, then delete or replace with next pdf.

Comment: @CDP1802 I guess, but I don't understand how will that help me. Just to clarify for example I copy the pdf to a folder name eg: Statement and all the pdf names will be statement.pdf?

Comment: It's simpler to code because it doesn't depend on the format of the filenames and it leaves the original pdf's untouched.

Comment: @CDP1802 Anyway I was going to use "working folder", so let's say I copy all the pdfs in to that folder. How do I chain using that value inside R.Offset(0, 3) to find me that particular pdf and then rename it to the folder's name where it's located? And how will I be sure it has attached the right pdf. I can open it and double check, while if the name is left I will be sure that it's working properly

Comment: Only the one file in the holding folder at any one time. Each iteration of the For Each R loop copies the `path & R.Offset(0, 3) + ".pdf"` as `attachment.pdf` and that gets attached to the email and sent.

Comment: `Set RList = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` to stop error with 1 line of data.

Comment: @CDP1802, thanks man it works, now, but still I don't undestand what to do with TempPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"

I think it's important , but for know it works, will try to generate 20 lines to see how it goes

Comment: 1st line - `Environ$("temp")` is the temp folder for the windows environment the code is operating in eg on my computer = `C:\Users\some username\AppData\Local\Temp`  2nd line ensures path has a trailing slash by adding one if it is not there.

Comment: @CDP1802 Well as said I don't have access to there and had to remove it.
Now this code works. 
Since this is my first time posting a question and I want to post the whole thing all together so if someone else has the same problem to just copy it and now gather pieces from the comments. But if I post it it would appear he answer to be mine when it is your's and CLR 's. What's the etiquette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script is to replace your For..Next loop. The rest can stay as is. It's untested, but the theory is sound I believe..

```
Dim foundfile As String, newfilename As String, TempPath As String

TempPath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\"

For Each R In RList

    'Find file that starts with number
    foundfile = Dir(Path & R.Offset(0, 3) & "*.pdf")
    
    'if file is found then..
    If foundfile <> "" Then
        'create new filename that excludes number
        newfilename = Mid(foundfile, InStr(foundfile, "_") + 1)
        
        'if file already exists in temp location, delete it
        If Dir(TempPath & newfilename) <> "" Then Kill TempPath & newfilename
        
        'create copy of file with short name in temp location
        FileCopy Path & foundfile, TempPath & newfilename
        
        Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
        With EItem
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = ("team_email")
            .To = R.Offset(0, 1)
            .Subject = R.Offset(0, 0)
            ' add attachment from temp location
            .Attachments.Add (TempPath & newfilename)
            .Display
            .HTMLBody = strbody & .HTMLBody
        End With
        'remove temporary copy
        Kill TempPath & newfilename
    Else
        'File not found
    End If
    
Next R
```

The routine locates the first file that begins with the number it's looking for in the source folder and copies it to a temporary location (while at the same time, renaming it without the digits). It then uses your existing script to attach the newly named file. Lastly, it then deletes (kills) the temporary file.

Comment: Just to clarify, Up there in my code in "path =" I put the path where all of the pdfs are located. then in your answer "TempPath=Environ$("temp) & "thefodlerwheremagichappnes\" " I create new folder thefodlerwheremagichappnes and the code will copy the pdf and put there to be renamed?

and here If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then Path = Path & "\" what do I put in the 2 "\"

Comment: Also this Environ$("temp") gets me some folder on my C drive that I don't have access( company restricted) so I tried removing it and directly inputing the path to the temp folder I've created. Your code works it but while there is only 1 row in excel and only 1 file the code creates new emails constantly and I have kill outlook to stop it.

Comment: Leave `Path = Path & "\"` as is - it's just to ensure the path ends with a "\"

Comment: Sorry about the `temp` solution. You can change that to any folder you do have access to.